# WCF service error on Windows 2008 servers

Tags: c#, wcf

We had one WCF service running on Windows 2003 servers, Recently we migrated to Windows 2008 servers.

When we make a call to the service we are getting following errors.

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to 
http://Example.service/HierarchyMgntService/Service.svc. This could be due 
to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also 
be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due 
to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
```

my web.config file look like this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <configuration>
     <system.web>
     <compilation debug ="true">
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"  enable = "True" 
    executionTimeout="45"/>
    </system.web>

     <appSettings>

    <add key="MaxThreadsCount" value="3" />
    <add key="CleanupThreadInterval" value="120000" />
    <add key="RequestRetryThreadInterval" value="10000" />
    <add key="InvokeCallsonThread" value="Y" />
    <add key="ThreadKillInterval" value="30" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
      <service name="HierarchyMgntService" behaviorConfiguration="MTServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="HIERARCHYMGNTSERVICE" address="http://Example/HIERARCHYMGNTSERVICE/Service.svc" binding="customBinding"
                            bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" contract="iHierarchyMgnt" />


        <endpoint name="MWServicemexEndpt" address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>


    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding"  openTimeout="10:00:00"
                  sendTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" closeTimeout="10:00:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304"
                          maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10485760"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MTServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10485760" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="75" maxConcurrentSessions="75"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <!-- Below Log entries message will be true when want to debug any issues otherwise it should be False-->
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="False" logMalformedMessages="False"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="False" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="False"
           maxMessagesToLog="5000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="4194304"/>
    </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="C:\WCFlogs\Messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                name="traceListener"
                initializeData="C:\WCFlogs\Traces.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

The call sometimes will work and failing for some other times. 
 Can somebody point me where can be the issue is

Comment: can you provide, end point config form your configuration files

Comment: i got the issue solved, The payload was large so APPool had exceeded  assigned Private memory. So i made the private memory as Zero and the call was successfull

Comment: Then add your solution here an answer.